# defiant.js?a1be:546 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: x10 is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
defiantSearch() {
  var start = Date.now()

  var self = this
  self.showLoader = true
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    // get the snapshot with a callback function
    Defiant.getSnapshot(self.masterData, function(snapshot) {
      console.log('Created snapshot in '+ (Date.now() - start) +' ms')
      // searching on snapshot created with web worker
      var found = JSON.search(snapshot, '//contents[title="' + self.searchText + '"]')
      self.searchResult = found
      console.log(found)
    })
    resolve()
  }) 
  self.showLoader = false
}
```

I am trying to use defiant.js in vuejs but  got error like 
defiant.js?a1be:546 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: x10 is not defined

Comment: I doubt it's related to error you get but you should call `resolve()` at the end of callback (after `console.log(found)`) and propably `self.showLoader` should be moved too, because it's after `return` statement

Comment: Commented the promise part still issue is not resolved!

Comment: `x10.js` is `defiant.js` dependency, your error may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/hbi99/defiant.js/issues/88) if you installed defiant using npm. Try using [dist](https://github.com/hbi99/defiant.js/tree/master/dist) version